# How to say ‘it’ when ‘it’ has no defined gender?

Tags: pronoms, genre

How do you say *it* when *it* has no defined gender?

For example in the phrase:

> Eat it!

Is the French translation “*mangez-la !* ” or “*mangez-le !* ”, or neither?

---

Also, aside from in “*c'est*” where is “*ce*” used?

Comment: The first question is answered there: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3326/gender-of-non-specific-antecedent (well enough, I dare say).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use *Mangez ça!*, although it's more a translation of *Eat that!*. Otherwise, by default you might use the masculine *Mangez-le!*.

**EDIT : I made a wrong assumption, thanks Stéphane for the heads-up**

<strike>Concerning *C'est*, it's a contraction of *Ceci est*. The word *ceci* is rather common place, and has pretty much the same meaning as *cela*, is the same way *this* and *that* have basically the same meaning.</strike>

Comment: Le pronom *c'* résulte de l'élision de *ce*, pas de *ceci* ou de *cela*. Au pluriel *c'est* devient *ce sont*. Une autre façon de le voir : la tournure avec sujet et verbe inversés est *est-ce*.

Comment: Oups... J'avais jamais eu l'idée de chercher le pluriel pour savoir ce que représente *c'*, je pensais bêtement (et à tort) que c'était *ceci*. Réponse corrigée!

Comment: Mon dieu, les francais font des fautes avec sa propre langue? Je me sens mieux maintenant.

Answer (score 8):

I would tend to say that your question is based on a false assumption: *"**it** has no defined gender"* - this situation should never happen in French at all as all nouns have a definite gender.

But yeah, in the case you don't want to name the thing or can't find a noun for it you can use "Mange ça!", or even simply "Mange!" if there's nothing else to eat. I'm deliberatley suggesting "Mange" instead of "Mangez" since I feel there isn't much respect involved at this point, but that would of course depend on the context.

Answer (score 1):

*Mange-le* ou *Mange-la* will most probably get the result you want.

The person will understand *Mange le fruit* ou *Mange la pomme* with the same end result.

In french every name has a gender, which is a mandatory syntactic attribute, not a matter of biology. We use it to know to which name relates an adjective (with an efficiency of 75%). As 50% of our vocabulary is masculine and 50% is feminine, you will always find a word with the appropriate gender describing your *it*.

In facts, if your *it* has no definite gender, *it* can only be amour, délice, orgue, gens, oeuvre, alvéole, après-midi, autoroute, enzyme, réglisse,... But even then, they take a gender as soon as they enter in a phrase.

About the distinction between grammatical and natural gender, did you know that according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender), in old English *wif* (wife) was neutral and *wifmann* (woman) was masculine ?