# Which subject pronoun to use with objects?

Tags: grammaire, genre

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to say 'it' when 'it' has no defined gender?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/how-to-say-it-when-it-has-no-defined-gender)

I can't seem to figure out the pattern for when different pronouns are used for objects. Sometimes it's "ce" and sometimes it's "il" or "elle," despite that the sentiment being expressed would in English amount to the same thing. Is there any pattern or reason?

Comment: Any examples of this, by any chance ?

Comment: Hmm...not on hand. Need some time.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to say 'it' when 'it' has no defined gender?](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2614/82), long story short there is no pattern for the grammatical gender of objects but it is meaningless and you can use *ça* if you don't want to explicit  it.

Comment: @Evpok Actually that question only pertains to pronouns as objects; I'm referring to them used as subjects. The information there is not pertinent. But I'm still looking for examples on my question anyway; I would say leave it closed until/unless I can edit it with some specific instances.

Comment: @Aerovistae No, neither the question nor the answers are explicitly restricted to objects, though the examples are. You can use *ça* as a subject, too, as is *Ça n'est pas très beau* ou *c'est joli* ; you can use *il* if the object is grammatically masculine, and *elle* if feminine, too.

Comment: Ah, but when is "ce" preferred over those three options?

Comment: @Aerovistae Perhaps you could include that in your question :)

Comment: Oh my, I forgot about this question. Soon to be edited.