# Gender of non-specific antecedent

Tags: pronoms, genre

If a noun hasn't been mentioned yet, how do we know what gender it has?

For example, suppose I make two cups of coffee, and I want to say to someone, "This one is for you," but I haven't mentioned the thing yet, the cup of coffee yet.

Now, a cup of coffee could be masculine (*un café*) or it could be feminine (*une tasse de café*). So which one should I say?:

- Celui-ci est pour toi.
- Celle-ci est pour toi.

Or must I say?:

- Ce café est pour toi.

Comment: Very related : http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2614/how-to-say-it-when-it-has-no-defined-gender

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the general case, I'd say every noun has a gender : as you mention, *une tasse* is feminine, and *un café* is masculine, and all is fine.

When it comes to the **object** you're talking about, since it wasn't already mentionned, it's totally **up to you** to introduce new items in the conversation.

You can hang that someone *un café* or *une tasse de café*, it's your choice, so specifically, you can say both, depending on what you want to refer to.

Answer (score 3):

Les pronoms neutres existent en français (*ce*, *ça*, *ceci*, *cela*). Avec l'exemple de la tasse :

- « C'est pour toi », dit-il en me tendant la tasse de café.
- « Elle est pour toi », dit-il en me tendant la tasse de café.
- « Il est pour toi », dit-il en me tendant la tasse de café.

sont parfaitement équivalents.

Comment: La troisième phrase est étrange, tout de même. Va pour *« il est pour toi », dit-il en me tendant un café*, mais le mélange des genres passe mal, trouvé-je. Ou alors, c'est vraiment pour mettre en avant le fait que le personnage et le narrateur n'envisagent pas l'objet dont il est question de la même façon, s'il faut capilotracter…

Comment: Not in the context: dangph made two cup of coffee, is pointing one to someone and wants to say that "this one (not the other) is yours". -- "Il est pour toi" sounds the standard for "C'u-ci, c'est l' tien".

Answer (score -2):

Not knowing the gender of a French noun seems as impossible as not knowing its first letter.

I understand that this information is phonetically hidden and you may feel uncomfortable grouping a noun with its article and adjectives. The only way is to learn noun phrases with  at least the article rather than isolated nouns.

Note that most of the time, you can go random. Statistically, you'll be right 50%. As you don't hear the final *e* of most adjectives, you'll be right more than 95% for adjectives. Only remains the article/possessive/demonstrative for which you have to count on tolerance from French native speakers.

In facts, telling me "*Celui/Celle-ci est pour toi*", already indicates me that French is not your first language. I know straight not have to rely on the gender to convey a significant information.

As the emphasis in on the cup of coffee, not what you do with it, the focus is on the possessive. So I would have expected:

- *C'est le tien* (for a cup of **coffee**).
- *C'est la tienne* (for a **cup** of coffee).

Your construct with *pour* is more used when you want to focus on the action:

- Celui-ci est pour boire.
- Celui-ci, je l'ai préparé pour toi